# Ubuntu 12.04 won't boot after Windows crash

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot

I am dual-booting Ubuntu 12.04 with Windows 7 home version. I installed it on November 3, and it has been working fine, sans some screen freezes that I've learned are a common issue.

Last night, I started having issues with Windows freezing shortly after logging in (the desktop would pop up and freeze after ~10-20 seconds). I tried doing a system restore from safe mode, to no avail. After playing a bit with the startup programs and services, I have it running normally again.

However, when I choose Ubuntu on the boot screen, it doesn't even get to the loading point. I see the errors "no wubildr" and "prefix not set," but I've seen these before with no consequence to the system actually running. After that, I just get a blank purple screen. I've waited ~5 minutes for something to happen, but nothing does. I don't get any sort of error messages, either.

In my C:/ drive, in ubuntu/disks, I notice that the root.disk file was modified yesterday at 4 PM, before I had any issues with Windows. All other files and applications have not been modified since November 3. So, it could be that this is an issue independent of the Windows crash. In any case, I don't really know where to start here. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you used the Wubi to install your Ubuntu. Basically it installs Ubuntu in the Windows directory and inserts boot options to allow you to select to boot to it during startup. Your Ubuntu install may be corrupt by the sound of it. Try the instructions in the link below to attempt to fix your Wubi install:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_can_I_access_my_Wubi_install_and_repair_my_install_if_it_won.27t_boot.3F